# Variable With Multiple Types

Tags: excel, vba, api

I created a couple years ago a few Excel spreadsheets which have VBA macros using a 3rd party API.

That API has been updated, but the changes are so minor that the only things that changed for my spreadsheets are a couple of variable types.

The old version was using those variable types :

`Dim ETABSObject As ETABS2016.cOAPI 
Dim SapModel As ETABS2016.cSapModel

Set ETABSObject = GetObject(, "CSI.ETABS.API.ETABSObject")
Set SapModel = ETABSObject.SapModel`

While the new version uses those types:

`Dim ETABSObject As ETABSv17.cOAPI
Dim SapModel As ETABSv17.cSapModel

Set ETABSObject = GetObject(, "CSI.ETABS.API.ETABSObject")
Set SapModel = ETABSObject.SapModel`

That's literally the only thing that is changing for me, replacing one by the other allows me to use my old spreadsheet with the new API.

Here's my problem: the software that was using the old API (ETABS16) is still being used as well, and I would like to avoid having to duplicate all my spreadsheets (creating a version for ETABS2016 and one for ETABSv17).

The variable `SapModel` is extensively used throughout the code, so having a `SapModel16` and a `SapModel17` variables is not really an option here.

Is there a way to declare `SapModel` in such a way that it would work for both versions of the API?

I tried declaring it as a `Variant` and then either setting it as `ETABSObject2016.SapModel` or `ETABSObjectv17.SapModel` using `on error GoTo`, but it didn't work. The `on error Goto` was able to identify which of the two versions of the API was being used, but the spreadsheet would be stuck at the first use of `SapModel`.

Comment: `Dim SapModel As Object` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @TimWilliams.
Declaring `SapModel` as an `Object` returns the error `Error 430: class does not support automation or does not support expected interface` soon after setting it to the correct version of the API.